# How to design a user permission handling database?

Tags: database, design-patterns, architecture

We have a little problem in one of our projects, where two investors are architects and... as it usually is in life, they don't really get along with some of the ideas. Both have different experiences with previous projects, and it seems they look down upon the ideas of the other one. Yep, I'm one of them.

We have an argument over how to define user permission handling in one our project.

One idea is to have table with permissions, roles which gather sets of permissions and then users who have a role defined.

```
User
user_id
role_id

Role
role_id
permission_id

Permission
permission_id
```

The other side would like to propose to do it using a table with columns defining permissions:

```
User
user_id
role_id

Role
role_id
can_do_something
can_do_something_else
can_do_something_even_different
```

My take on the first option is that it's far cheaper to maintain:
adding a single permission means it's just one insert + handling of the permission in the code.

In case of the other (to me) it means that you have to alter the database, alter the code handling the database and on top of that, add code to handle the permission.

But maybe I'm just wrong, and I don't see some possible benefits of the other solution.

I always thought the former is the standard to handle it, but I'm told that it's subjective and that making a change in the database is a matter of just running a script (where for me it means that the script has to be added to the deployment, has to be run on every database and in case of migration has to be "remembered" etc.)

I know the question could be opinion based, but I'm kind of hoping, this really is a matter of standards and good practice, rather then subjective opinion.

Comment: Is your Role model flat, or will it have a hierarchy of sort? i.e. if I am, say "Root" do I automatically get all privileges of "NormalUser" and "AreaManager" (which in turns is "above" normal user and so it has NormalUser privileges, too?). Alternatively, can Roles be members of other roles, or only users can be associated to Roles? Only one role for user, or more than one role ?

Comment: Do users get a set of context data to go along with their roles? I.e. if I am an AreaManager, do I get somewhere an area code (to identify the area I manage, and then I have update privileges on that area, but read-only privileges on other areas?) - this could also include, for a manager, who reports to him/her, so that I get maybe a privilege to add or remove users "under" me, but no update allowed on users from other departments.

Comment: @p.marino: role root will have to have all permissions added which are required. roles will not contain links to other roles. We don't expect to be area related, it's more like client related. if you are a client and you create your manager you will apply a role to it. You can create your own roles for that.

Comment: In my experience it is usually better to have roles to be composable. I.e. you design a role as HeadLibrarian, then make it a member of roles Staff,  Library Users, Dept.Manager. 
Why? because when John Smith - who is your HeadLibrarian - leaves the company and is replaced by Susan Black you will have to assign her only one role, and not 3 (and you have to delete only one role association for the guy who resigns, instead of three). Of course YMMV - my experience has been with companies with thousands of employees, tens of Roles and tens of Departments or DataSets to grant privileges on.

Comment: One more thing: will role have to be queried by GUI to decide what elements to display or make actionable? (like Role=Manager will make button "FireOnTheSpot" visible on the GUI and active), while button EditProfle will be visible to everyone but active only when you are looking at your own profile?

Answer (score 2):

I posted some other questions as comments to your original question.

Even if you had a completely flat role setup I cannot think of a reason to go for the second proposal. As you argue changing something will require modifying code *and* data structure.

What your colleague is proposing is a sort of denormalization which is only defensible in case you need to optimize for speed in handling large quantities of data. Which is not usually the case when dealing with roles.

(As an example, LDAP or other general-purpose single-sign-on models adopt something closer to your first solution, because even in a large organization the number of USERS is always larger than the number of ROLES by at least one order of magnitude).

Even if you were designing a Facebook replacement (where you may have billions of users) it is really improbable that you will need more than a handful of roles so this would be a case of premature optimization (and - most probably - made worse by optimizing the wrong part).

---

In a more general sense I strongly suggest to read the [RBAC Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) for what is considered the standard approach to this kind of problems.

Comment: Great answer, even though I think the question should be closed as primarily opinion based

Comment: @tomredfern yes, that's what I was worried about at the beginning, but at the same time, I think well... there are standards and patterns.

Comment: @Krystian: I have worked with role-based models used for SSO and to administer/access WebPortals and the predominant model was always closer to the first solution than to the second.